# EntityDataSource ,Select * From?

Tags: asp.net, entitydatasource

for example,

```
    <asp:EntityDataSource ID="edsPatient" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="name=ReferralDBEntities" 
        DefaultContainerName="ReferralDBEntities" EnableFlattening="False" 
        EntitySetName="Patients" 
        Select="it, (it.FirstName + it.LastName) as FullName"

        >
```

But it is not perform to SQL :

```
Select p.*, (p.FirstName + p.LastName) as FullName from Patients p
```

Is it EntityDataSource not support wildcard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CoachName" SortExpression="FullName">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DDLPeopleID" runat="server"  CssClass="dropdown"
DataSourceID="PeopleEntityDS" DataTextField="FullName"  AppendDataBoundItems="true"
DataValueField="PeopleID"   SelectedValue='<%# Bind("CoachID") %>'>
<asp:ListItem Text="" value=""></asp:ListItem> </asp:DropDownList>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

   <asp:EntityDataSource ID="PeopleEntityDS" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="name=EQnetTableEntities" 
        DefaultContainerName="EQnetTableEntities" 
        EntitySetName="People"  AutoGenerateWhereClause ="false"
        Select="it.[PeopleID],(it.[FirstName]+' '+it.[LastName]) as FullName" OrderBy="it.PeopleID" 
         EnableFlattening="False">
    </asp:EntityDataSource>
```

Comment: Why have you posted two different answers to the same question?

Answer (score 1):

```
asp:TemplateField   => DataTextField="FullName"  
EntityDatasource    =>  Select="it.[PeopleID],(it.[FirstName]+' '+it.[LastName]) as FullName"
```